# Writing to Multiple files simultaneously

Tags: c++, io

I need to export some data into an ORC file. i can either export all the data into a single file using one thread (since using several thread is useless in that case), or i can either write my data into several smaller files using multiple threads.

my question is wehther writing into multiple smaller files can be done simultaneously? will it improve performance?
also, writing to a larger file is slower than writing to a smaller file? if yes why?

Thanks

Comment: This depends a little bit on the amount of data you want to write. In most cases one big file, written in a single thread will do. Do you have more information that you could share?

Comment: the size of the file can vary from very small to very big. i thought making small files of 100MB tops instead of one big file